# php - Time remaining until specific time from current time of page load

Tags: php, time

I have to admit that having not even tried to code this myself this question may be a annoying to some but I'm very surprised that I wasn't able to find a good example on the web of what I'm trying to do. Perhaps I'm just not using the right key words in my searches.

I am trying to calculate the time remaining from now (the time the page loads) until a specific date and time (let's say Wednesday May 11, 2011 12:00PM for example) and display it. I had thought it would be quite easy to find a snippet to accomplish this but no luck so far. Does anyone have some example code they have used to accomplish this before? I don't expect anyone to write this for me from scratch but if I can at least get pointed in the right direction it would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I'd use the [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) and [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) functions:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$future_date = new DateTime('2011-05-11 12:00:00');

$interval = $future_date->diff($now);

echo $interval->format("%a days, %h hours, %i minutes, %s seconds");
```

You'll need a version of PHP that's at least 5.3 to do it this way - otherwise, do what [helloandre recommends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906686/php-time-remaining-until-specific-time-from-current-time-of-page-load/5906711#5906711).

Comment: be careful though, as this is only available in 5.2+

Comment: its not working for date that has been passed away. now - past, should says 0 days, 0 seconds etc, but its not

Comment: using if($future_date <= $now)exit("Link is expired.");

Comment: I'm considering using this code but as a noob, where is DateInterval() used? I only see references to DateTime()

Answer (score 5):

I think it will usefull

```
$startdate="2008-06-22 20:38:25"; 
$enddate="2008-06-29 21:38:49"; 

$diff=strtotime($enddate)-strtotime($startdate); 
echo "diff in seconds: $diff<br/>\n<br/>\n"; 

// immediately convert to days 
$temp=$diff/86400; // 60 sec/min*60 min/hr*24 hr/day=86400 sec/day 

// days 
$days=floor($temp); echo "days: $days<br/>\n"; $temp=24*($temp-$days); 
// hours 
$hours=floor($temp); echo "hours: $hours<br/>\n"; $temp=60*($temp-$hours); 
// minutes 
$minutes=floor($temp); echo "minutes: $minutes<br/>\n"; $temp=60*($temp-$minutes); 
// seconds 
$seconds=floor($temp); echo "seconds: $seconds<br/>\n<br/>\n"; 

echo "Result: {$days}d {$hours}h {$minutes}m {$seconds}s<br/>\n"; 
echo "Expected: 7d 0h 0m 0s<br/>\n"; 


echo "time isss".time();

echo   $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s')";

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

first you'll need to calculate the difference in seconds using `time()` and `strtotime()`. Then you can translate those seconds into days/hours/minutes/seconds.