# Display Days/Hours Until Certain Time

Tags: php, datetime

I need to calculate the remaining time (days/hours) until a certain date/time.

However, I'm not using a static date.

Imagine I have an event at 17:00 hrs on **every Sunday**. I need to display the time remaining until the next event, i.e. the oncoming Sunday 17:00.

I've found the following code in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5906737/171318). It works for a static date/time, but obviously isn't what I'm looking for.

```
$now = new DateTime();
$future_date = new DateTime('2011-05-11 12:00:00');
$interval = $future_date->diff($now);
echo $interval->format("%d days, %h hours, %i minutes, %s seconds");
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the relative time format `next Sunday 17:00`. Like this:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$future_date = new DateTime('next Sunday 17:00');
$interval = $future_date->diff($now);
echo $interval->format("%d days, %h hours, %i minutes, %s seconds");
```

Output:

```
6 days, 2 hours, 33 minutes, 53 seconds
```

Read more about relative time formats here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Comment: duplicate answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906686/php-time-remaining-until-specific-time-from-current-time-of-page-load

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed.
@cardeol Please read my question before rushing to find another question. The question you linked to doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @mmmbaileys You are welcome. Relative time formats are really powerful. Check also the documentation page that I've linked.

Comment: FWIW - I ended up using "('this Sunday 17:00');" instead of "('next Sunday 17:00');". Suited my needs more.