# Future timeago method in PHP or JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, timeago

I was browsing for STO and web for this, but coudn't find anything for this.

I'm looking for a method/function to print out a readable **future timeago**, like:

- *In 3 hours from now*
- *In 1 year from now*

I'm storing dates in the future into my datetime column in my table and I need it to predict how much time is left when it's published, etc.

Is there anything like this done already? If so - please help.

**This is my current *timeago* in PHP:**

(I also have a localized version of this method for Serbian-Croatian-Bosnian language)

```
public static function time_elapsed($ptime) {
    $etime = time() - $ptime;

    if ($etime < 1) {
        return '0 seconds';
    }

    $a = array(12 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 => 'year',
        30 * 24 * 60 * 60 => 'month',
        24 * 60 * 60 => 'day',
        60 * 60 => 'hour',
        60 => 'min',
        1 => 'sec'
    );

    foreach ($a as $secs => $str) {
        $d = $etime / $secs;
        if ($d >= 1) {
            $r = round($d);
            return $r . ' ' . $str . ($r > 1 ? 's' : '') . ' ago';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean... Please elaborate.

Comment: It's a date in the future, like 2014-07-31, > 3 weeks from now... I'm posting my code in the post, please wait.

Comment: Reversed timeago to me means you have the string "3 years from now" and want  a date. In PHP you would use `strtotime('now + 3 years')`  to get the timestamp which you can use `date()` to format into a date. You haven't said where you're getting the string "in 3 years from now" in the first place.

Comment: No, I don't want a date because I already have it stored in the table. I want to convert that date into a readable string, like: "666 years from now", etc.

Comment: I have said already: I have a timeago solution! I need that thing vice-versed now.

Comment: Updated ambiguous title.

Comment: This is essentially just a countdown. Try [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=php+countodwn&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=ww28U_z_CuLR8ge61IGoDg#channel=fflb&q=php+countdown&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&spell=1)

Comment: @Popnoodles - Ok. Thank you on that. I didn't know how to express myself on this matter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906686/php-time-remaining-until-specific-time-from-current-time-of-page-load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this if i understood what you want correctly:

```
function time_elapsed($ptime) {
    $etime = $ptime - time();

    if ($etime < 1) {
        return '0 seconds';
    }

    $a = array(12 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 => 'year',
        30 * 24 * 60 * 60 => 'month',
        24 * 60 * 60 => 'day',
        60 * 60 => 'hour',
        60 => 'min',
        1 => 'sec'
    );

    foreach ($a as $secs => $text) {
        $d = $etime / $secs;
        if ($d >= 1) {
            $r = round($d);
            return "In " . $r . ' ' . $text . ($r > 1 ? 's' : '') . ' from now';
        }
    }
}

$time_elapsed = time_elapsed(time() + 36000); // prints In 10 hours from now 
var_dump($time_elapsed);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using http://momentjs.com/.  It has the functionality you're looking for.  See http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/from/

Example:

```
<script>
var my_date = moment('2014-07-07');
$("#date").val(start.from(my_date) + " from now"); // "in 5 days from now"
</script>
```

Comment: @zlomerovic It can be installed via npm, bower, or manually.  This presumes you want the time manipulation on the client side.

Comment: No, I'm doing this on server side. But thanks anyway.