# Get different time to end of the current day

Tags: php, datetime

Good time.
How can i Get different time to end of the current day?
For example i would like get this output when i run my PHP script:

```
19 hours 35 minutes 13 seconds to end of current day
```

Thanks

Comment: can you describe more what you want and what problem you are facing during implementing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Comment: duplicate [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906686/php-time-remaining-until-specific-time-from-current-time-of-page-load) Next time use google... faster than asking a duplicated question

Comment: @Amirm Hope my post will help you out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help you out..

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/783688)

```
echo remainingTime();
function remainingTime()
{
    $string="";
    $date=  date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $endDate= date("Y-m-d")." 23:59:59";
    $remainingSeconds=strtotime($endDate)-strtotime($date);
    $string.=gmdate("H", $remainingSeconds)." hours ";
    $string.=gmdate("i", $remainingSeconds)." minutes ";
    $string.=gmdate("s", $remainingSeconds)." seconds to the end of current day";
    return $string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this concept:

```
/**
 * Calculate the remaining time of the day in procedural style
 */

//get current time
$now = time();
//get tomorrow's time
$tomorrow = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d') + 1, date('Y'));

//get the remaining time in second
$rem =  $tomorrow - $now;
```

$rem is the remaining time in seconds. You just need to divide it by 60 to get how many minutes. Divide it again by 60 to get how many hours.

Reference [Howto: Calculate remaining time](https://www.intechgrity.com/howto-calculate-the-remaining-time-of-the-day-in-php/#)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$datetime1 = new DateTime();
$datetime2 = new DateTime('tomorrow');
$datetime2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%h hours %i minutes %s seconds');

?>
```

Possible output is **8 hours 38 minutes 46 seconds**